# Is there any way to remove empty regions with ReSharper cleanup?

Tags: c#, resharper

I want ReSharper to remove empty regions on code cleanup.

```
#region

#endregion
```

Is there any setting?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit -> Replace in Files** (regular expression)

unnamed regions

```
#region[\r\n\t ]*#endregion
```

named regions

```
[ ]*#region \w*[\r\n\t ]*#endregion \w*[ ]*
```

Run a cleanup of your code afterwards to get rid of the empty lines